# how to export the file names of several files into an excel sheet?

Tags: windows, file, filenames

I have a folder full of files like "stackoverflow_2010_A.gif" "stackoverflow_2010_RU.gif" etc and I would like to export the list of file names (that is "stackoverflow_2010_A.gif" etc) into an excel sheet so that I can work on them. Do you know how to proceed on windows 7?

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a text file with the filenames and then import it in Excel. Try this in a command prompt in the directory where the image files are located:

```
DIR /B Stackoverflow*.gif > files.txt
```

Edit: to add a prefix to the file names in the output file you can use the sed utility. I tested the following using GNU sed 4.2.1 for Windows which is available from [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm). The command will add `prefix_`to all file names.

```
dir /b Stackoverflow*.gif | sed "s/^/prefix_/" > files.txt
```

Comment: thank you very much your this wonderful answer! just another point: is it possible to add a prefix to the files written in the .txt file? for instance add jpw_ to every file? (jpw_stackoverflow_2010_A.gif) thank you so much!

Comment: @Noobie It's kind of tricky in the normal command shell, but it's easy if you use the `sed`utility. I've updated my answer with an example.